# Detecting loss of WiFi connection in OkHttp3

Tags: android, android-wifi, okhttp

When OkHttp3 calls the `onFailure` callback, it passes an `IOException`. Is there a specific subclass of `IOException` that will indicate that the target device has disappeared from the WiFi network? Is there another way to detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) has several sub-classes; while it may be save to assume that something went offline - because when the *own* network connection is still alive, it has to be the other side of the connection. when it throws an `IOException`, that's an `IOExcpetion`; casting it won't add any more information.

the state of the *own* network connection can be detected, but not with `OkHttp3`. here's an example for that on my [GitHub](https://github.com/syslogic/androidx-github/tree/master/mobile/src/main/java/io/syslogic/github/network); see class `ConnectivityListener` and class `ConnectivityReceiver`.

How would you detect the state of another host's network connection?
this can be tested, by switching off the WiFi network of either device; both situations would cause an `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks. I was imagining that the author of OkHttp3 might create a subclass of `IOException`, perhaps called something like `ServerNotRespondingException` and throw that when appropriate (The Bluetooth LE library `RxAndroidBle` has a wealth of such custom exceptions to give detail about failures). Even one of the standard subclasses like `InterruptedByTimeoutException` or `IIOException` might be better than the rather vague `IOException`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RobertLewis `e.getCause()` might be the best chance to get a little more information, when such a standard `IOException` is being thrown. "server not responding" and "request timeout" are probably easier to detect than "host not available" (where the state of either network interface can be the cause for that).

Comment: the mere difference might also be, that a BLE library controls the BT interface, while a HTTP client implementation assumes whatever network interface & gateway to be present ...